# Java drawString() very slow on start up

Tags: java, performance, drawstring

I'm new to Java programming and am having difficulty with the drawString method delaying almost a full second before drawing after the JFrame appears. Here is the test class I ran to verify it was drawString causing the delay(I'm sorry it is written out, I'm posting on my phone):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame{
    JPanel jp;
    Container c;

    Frame1(){
        setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        c = getContentPane();
        c.add(jp = new JPanel(){
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                g.drawString("hello", 20, 20);
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Frame1();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use drawString without this delay? I'm using a MacBook Pro with Mac OSX 10.6.3. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The short answer is, not really.  You could make sure that you starting the UI withing the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.  You really should be overriding `paintComponent` (and calling `super.paintComponent`) instead of `paint`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Y U No make it an answer?

Comment: @devaldcool It's not really an answer, but simply a series of suggestions. There might be something else which actually does improve the performance...

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK7_60 on Windows 7.